# Changing Python Version cause : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I've been trying to downgrade my python from 3.8 to 3.6.9 for my odoo 14 project but after successfuly changing python3 version and restarting odoo i get this :

> Traceback (most recent call last): Sep 03 11:44:45 :   File
> "/usr/bin/odoo", line 5, in  Sep 03 11:44:45 :     import odoo
> Sep 03 11:44:45: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo' Sep 03
> 11:44:45 : odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status> Sep
> 03 11:44:45 : odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I don't what the steps i'm missing but if anyone is familiar with this error give me some hints and thank you for your time.

Comment: are you using windows or linux machine? You should verify also if the installation was inside an virtual env, if so don't forget to create a new environment with Python3.6.9 and reinstall the odoo in it.

Comment: @AjayRathore hey i'm working with Linux . I just reinstalled odoo requirement and it worked fine for me :)

Comment: @nessHaf Can you list the steps please. Im trying some system which is giving me t his error. I really hate python because of these crazy dependency hell issues.